# What is the reason of [TypeError: v.p.u is not a function] error in Lightning?

Tags: javascript, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

Faced today with the strange error saying: [TypeError: v.p.u is not a function]

Approximately fails from lines 393-394 of aura_prod.js

Does anyone know if we can replace standard Salesforce Aura Javascript libraries to debug?

It doesn't seem to be convenient to debug Salesforce minified Javascript code

Comment: Are you sure it is caused by the Aura JS itself and not due to your code passing in values of v.p.u as a function call?

Comment: You should raise a case with salesforce support .aura.js is owned by SFDC and they should be able to help you with cause of issue .Thanks

Comment: You can turn on debug mode: From Setup, enter Lightning Components in the Quick Find box, then select Lightning Components.
Select the Enable Debug Mode checkbox.

Comment: Any other possible cause of the error? Anything that you were working on prior to this breaking?

Comment: @Eric Yes,I am sure. I have no 'v.p.u' hardcoded in my code. And 393-394 lines of minified javascript file aura_prod.js have it, but it is hard to debug minified javascript

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I don't want to open a new case with SFDC support since this is not really helpful. I have opened a lot of cases against SFDC support and they never really helped to me. They are super slowly and are investigating critical issues for months, if I worked like them, I would get fired

Comment: @CasparHarmer Actually I have figured out that if I remove debug formula {!v.customModelClassRecord.listOfAnotherCustomModelClassRecords} that this issue doesn't happen, but still I couldn't nail it to minimal reproducible case